# Where do you put global variables in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, global-variables

In **PHP** web programming, I always made a **singleton Output object** in which I could put **global** information that had to be available from any line of code.

So in **WPF** applications, I create the following class to perform the same function, e.g. the variable **`ReturnToPageIdCode`** returns the page to which another page is supposed to return to after processing some task, and I can set and get that value anywhere I want.

This works nicely.

However, I can't help to think that in the **stateful** WPF environment, I'm **recreating the wheel** with this singleton Output object.

**Where do you put hold application-wide values in your WPF applications? Is there some standard place to do this?**

```
public class Output
{
    private Output output;

    private static Output instance;

    public string ReturnToPageIdCode { get; set; }

    public static Output GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new Output();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public string GetTestMessage()
    {
        return "This is a global test message from the output singleton.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Globals? just say no. (sorry, someone had to say it) for config stuff, as suggested by others, use the App.Config, 
The code you provided looks like a [M-V-VM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) to me--you should check it out.  WPF, by it's nature, promotes this. Learn it, love it, live it.

Comment: thanks for the clear thinking, I deleted my Output object and put e.g. ReturnToPageIdCode into a PageManager object that I was injecting into every page anyway, makes sense

Answer (score 4):

I consider the sort of global state that I *think* you're describing to be configuration information.  Resultantly, I place it in the App.config file, generally through the project's properties' "Settings" tab.

This will expose your configuration information through `<WhateverNamespace>.Properties.Settings` where it's easy to access in a typesafe manner.

If you're describing something else, such as mutable application state that isn't configuration information, I'd strongly suggest shifting your paradigm to a more client-application form where such global state is strongly frowned upon due to it's error-prone nature.  IE, restructure your application model so that it doesn't depend on global data-- use parameters and objects instead.

Answer (score 3):

[App.Config](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ApplicationSettings.aspx) (double click the Properties node in the project) for primitives that are user specific (read/write) and application specific (read only).

For complex types such as providers (database, logging, etc), there isn't "one" place.  But the best pattern today is to use some form of [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) such as [Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd140117.aspx) or [NInject](http://ninject.org/).

Comment: +1 for including Dependency Injection (even if it has to be manual constructor injection).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  /// <summary>
    /// "Global variables" or kind of "Session State" class.
    /// To save a variable: ApplicationState.SetValue("currentCustomerName", "Jim Smith");
    /// To read a variable: MainText.Text = ApplicationState.GetValue<string>("currentCustomerName");
    /// </summary>
    public static class ApplicationData
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Get an application-scope resource Formatted News
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DataContainerModel GetNews()
        {
            var  formattedNews = (DataContainerModel)Application.Current.Resources["FormattedNews"];
            return formattedNews;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set an application-scope resource Formatted News
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dataContainerModel"></param>
        public static void SetNews(DataContainerModel dataContainerModel)
        {
            Application.Current.Resources["FormattedNews"] = dataContainerModel;
        }

        private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> _values = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();

        public static void SetValue(string key, object value)
        {
            if (_values.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                var oldValue = new object();
                _values.TryRemove(key, out oldValue);
            }
            _values.TryAdd(key, value);
        }

        public static T GetValue<T>(string key)
        {
            if (_values.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                return (T)_values[key];
            }
            else
            {
                return default(T);
            }
        }

    }
```

So here you see two approaches. I would like to have both of them.

Oh! `DataContainerModel`  is going to be any custom class you need.

Answer (score 0):

While I share the general lack of enthusiasm for globals, it's worth at least acknowledging the central WPF mechanism for global information:  the application's resource dictionary.  There are a lot of things you shouldn't use this for (like, you can create a singleton-like object just by putting an XML data source in your application's resource dictionary, but really, don't), but there are a lot of things that you should - global styles, global templates, etc.